# How to build recursive function which only remembers every pth value and the last two values?

Tags: compile, recursion

I need to create a recursive function of the natural numbers $f$ which only remembers the last two values it has found and every $p$th value. Below is the form of the code that I am working with, but it remembers every value it's found. I would normally be fine with remembering everything, but for me each $f(n)$ is essentially a 500x500 matrix which starts to hog RAM.

```
Fib[1] = 1;
Fib[2] = 1;
Fib[n_] := mkFib[n]=mkFib[n - 1] + mkFib[n - 2];
cFib = Compile[{{n, _Integer, 0}}, mkFib[n]];
cFib[6]
```

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: a) Your current code won't work since `mkFib` is not defined, and b) If you only need to remember the last two values you're probably better off doing it iteratively.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a recursive solution, you should first rewrite `Fib` to return both the last values, so it only needs one recursive call - thus making the number of recursive calls grow linearly instead of exponentially with `n` (or `p`, if partially memoized):

```
Clear[recFib]
recFib[2] = {1, 1};
recFib[n_] := 
  Module[{last = recFib[n - 1]}, {last[[-1]], Total[last]}];
fib[n_] := Last[recFib[n]]
```

Adding "partial memoization" is straightforward, if not as elegant as the `f[x_] := f[x_] = ...` ideom:

```
Clear[recFib]
recFib[2] = {1, 1};
recFib[n_] := Module[
  {
   last = recFib[n - 1],
   result
   },
  (
   result = {last[[-1]], Total[last]};
   (* memoize every 5th result *)
   If[Mod[n, 5] == 0, recFib[n] = result];
   (* return result *)
   result
   )]
```

**Edit**: You can make it a bit more readable by separating the memoization and the calculation logic:

```
Clear[partialMemoize, recFib]
partialMemoize[symbol_[parameter_], result_, p_: 5] :=
 (
  If[Mod[parameter, p] == 0, symbol[parameter] = result];
  result
  )
SetAttributes[partialMemoize, HoldFirst]
recFib[2] = {1, 1};
recFib[n_] := Module[
  {last = recFib[n - 1]}, 
  partialMemoize[recFib[n], {last[[-1]], Total[last]}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple procedural method:

```
Clear[f, g]; f[1] = 1; f[0] = 1; f[-1] = 0; p = 5;
Do[f[n] = f[n - 1] + f[n - 2]; Unset[f[n - 3]]; 
     If[Mod[n, p] == 0, g[n] = f[n]];, {n, 2, 20}]
```

If you now query the values of `?f` you can see only the final ones, while `?g` stores only every pth entry.